# IntelliJ or VS Code for angular development

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

What is best for angular development? I am using visual studio code but I use IntelliJ for other things so I was wondering if there were any benefits to moving from VS Code to IntelliJ.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate. Both tools can be used. Are there particular features or behaviors that are important to you. VS Code is probably more popular than intellij for angular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use both VSCode and Intellij WebStorm.

There are thousands and thousands of useful VSCode extensions and we can do anything with them.

But I prefer the IntelliJ WebStorm when working with Angular projects.

We do not have any materials that compare these 2 products. Here is a list of WebStorm Angular features:

- Advanced code completion: completion and navigation for Angular components, directive, methods, data-bindings, and more
- Support for Angular Material: completion and navigation for Material components and attributes
- Integration with Angular CLI:

  - Create a new project from the IDE Welcome screen
  - Generate new Angular components, services, directives from the IDE, without using the console
- Rename refactoring for components that updates the component definition, all the file names and all the usages of this component both in TypeScript and HTML files
- Angular code snippets (AKA live templates)
- Integration with the Angular language service: errors highlighting and code completion
- Run and debug Angular apps in the IDE
- Run and debug Karma and Protractor tests in the IDE

All these features can also be used in VS Code with some installation of extensions. But the key is that we don't need any additional installation step with Web Storm.

I am not comparing the products. It was only my opinion. Some of the contents are taken from IntelliJ community.